# Data of abstract model resolution

Tags: pyomo

I'm starting with pyomo and I have some questions.

I create an abstract model and the correspondenting data file. I would like to solve it in the script in order to use the solutions of the variables later. 
I tried to do it with the next code:

```
data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename="Datos\Datos_reactor2.dat")
instance = model.create_instance(data)  
opt = SolverFactory("ipopt")
results = opt.solve(instance)
```

And it solve it perfectly, but **I had some problems with the data**. In my model there aren't set, so the data are simple constants defined as:

```
param qv := 2.832;
param ci := 14.46;
...
```

However if I use this data file python tell me an error:

```
ValueError: Parameter 'qv' defined with '1' dimensions, but data has '1' values: [2.832]. Are you missing a value for a 1-dimensional index?
```

When I change my data file defining the parameters like:

```
param qv := 1  2.832;
param ci := 1  14.46;
...
```

I got another error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to set value for param=qv, index=1, value=2.832. source error message="Error setting parameter value: Cannot treat the scalar Param 'qv' as an array"
```

Finally, to can solve the problem I have to define the constants as tables (see beolw), but I don't understand the previous errors.

```
table qv := 2.832;
table ci := 14.46;
...
```

To highlight just say that if I try to solve the problem with:

```
!pyomo solve Reactor2.py Datos_reactor.dat --solver=ipopt --summary
```

With the data defined as in the first case (param qv := 2.832; ...) I don't have any problem and I got the same solution.

Can anyone tell me the difference and explain me the errors?

Thank you!!

Maria

Comment: For completeness, this is a confirmed bug and already on the issue tracker https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/120